# The DOM doesn't react on a fast Drag & Drop (ng2-dnd of Angular2)

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

While trying the [ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd) on an `angular2` application, I've succeeded in making it work properly **EXCEPT** when I drag & drop an item quickly (`< 1s`) a relevant method (`console.log`) wouldn't be fired.
HTML part :

```
<ul dnd-sortable-container [sortableData]="categories">
   <li
    (onDropSuccess)="transferDataSuccess($event)"
    dnd-sortable
    [sortableIndex]="idx"
    *ngFor="let category of categories; let idx = index"
   >
{{category.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And that's the method in TS file:

```
transferDataSuccess(e) {
    console.log(this.categories)
  }
```

Is there any workaround to make it respond to every drag & drop change ?

Comment: Hi, would you mind sharing dnd-sortable-container directive?

Comment: I do not get it ? that's the whole code .. `dnd-sortable-container` is a dnd built-in directive

Comment: Sorry my mistake, confused it with something else...